# Maintain retry state during async that throws exception

Tags: exception, asynchronous

So I have a UI thread.  Person clicks something because they feel like it.  So click triggers some function calls.  One of the underlying function calls uses CDROM driver that reads dirty discs by trying a couple of times and making that crazy thumping.

So I want a responsive UI and i put await on my function call.  So when person clicks, function relinquishes control to UI thread.  Function tries to read the CDROM, but it is really dirty so it throws an exception to its caller.  That caller counts the number of retries and keeps trying three times.

So, if this is all await, where do I keep the count?

If I keep the count in a lower level and that level relinquishes with await, it can't keep retrying until three attempts because IT IS RELINQUISHED.

But if I don't relinquish, I can't maintain a responsive UI.

Do I keep the count in the Task object?  And exactly which thread/await level can be responsible for checking the retry count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your retry logic wherever is most appropriate. `await` works perfectly well with `try`:

```
public async Task PerformOperationAsync(int retries)
{
  while (retries != 0)
  {
    try
    {
      await PerformSingleOperationAsync();
      return;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      Log(ex);
      --retries;
    }
  }
}
```

The code above will ignore failures if it runs out of retries. You can also throw the last error:

```
public async Task PerformOperationAsync(int retries)
{
  while (true)
  {
    try
    {
      await PerformSingleOperationAsync();
      return;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      Log(ex);
      if (--retries == 0)
        throw;
    }
  }
}
```

Throwing the first error or a collection of all the errors is left as an exercise for the reader. ;)

Comment: So if all retries are exhausted what do I do?    ....  If the await succeeds, it will execute the callback pointer in Task object.  If this level function determines that await has tried enough how does it indicate to the/interrupt the; caller? This.oTask.failed?

Comment: You can do whatever you want to do. The code I posted just gives up (without an error) if the retries are all used up. You can choose to re-throw the exception instead if you want.

Comment: Can the UI thread abort the while loop? Say the user decides that he should just go buy another copy of the disk.

Comment: Cancellation is best handled by `CancellationToken`, which you can trigger from a button click or whatnot. The [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx) describes how to define cancelable `async` methods.

Comment: I will look into System.Threading.Tasks.TasksStatus.RanToCompletion and Faulted.  Also, I will look into System.IProgress.  I would like to know how to reconcile the concept of the task throwing an exception or ending with Faulted state.  Thanks for your forbearance.